# Issue with importing com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a basic java project wherein I have imported the jersey-client-1.19.jar externally in my java build (using eclipse). I am trying to write a basic jersey client to make a RESTful call to a web service. As soon as I try to import the ClientResponse class, eclipse complains about -

the type javax.ws.rs.ext.runtimedelegate$headerdelegate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

Eclipse auto correct takes me to my build paths. But I have had no luck fixing this. Googled for this but did not find anything.

I am missing something basic here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never mind. Fixed it by trying to import jars from jersey library. The jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar import fixed the issue.

Comment: @BhushanPatil - I never thought this will be useful to anyone but I have accepted my own fix as the answer :)