# Java classes fails

Tags: java

I have a project that fails in one class, i think that the project cant find the classes. Help please, i dont know how to solve it. Why are happen this?

```
The type javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate$HeaderDelegate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

It is failing in the declaration of the package.

Comment: Can you tell more about the project ? Is it a web based project or standalone ? Also have a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958710/issue-with-importing-com-sun-jersey-api-client-clientresponse

Comment: You need to have in your classpath the jar containing javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate$HeaderDelegate

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the below dependency to your pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it works , thank you. But i have another library that miss. The type com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files